# ngCordova media player: media is not defined

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework to create a mobile app and testing it on my browser at the moment.

ng-click="play('music/work.mp3')" //on a button

```
<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script><!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script> 

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
.controller('ChatsCtrl',function($cordovaMedia,$ionicLoading,$ionicPopup,$scope,$ionicTabsDelegate,$ionicScrollDelegate,repository,$ionicModal) { 

$scope.play = function(src){
    console.log('trytrytryyyyyyyyy');
    var media = new Media(src, null, null, mediaStatusCallback); 
    $cordovaMedia.play(media);
}
var mediaStatusCallback = function(status) {
    if(status == 1) {
        $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Loading...'});
    } else {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    }
}
```

I used the following code. I get this error. I don't know what I did wrong. I following this instruction  https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/11/playing-audio-android-ios-ionicframework-app/
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phonegap: Uncaught ReferenceError: Media is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985980/phonegap-uncaught-referenceerror-media-is-not-defined)

Comment: @Abhijeet OP not using any phonegap, its purely Cordova

Comment: @unisound , media will not be working in browser, you need to test it in real device only